# When to not use neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Neo4j is a great tool for mapping relational data, but I am curious what under what conditions it would not be a good tool to use.

In which use cases would using neo4j be a bad idea?

Comment: get ready for the SO lynchmob

Comment: Extremely high write loads is one anti-use case: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558589/neo4j-sharding-aspect

Comment: See also this [post](https://www.quora.com/What-was-the-reason-for-Facebook-team-to-avoid-using-Neo4J-for-the-Social-Graph) on why FaceBook doesn't use Neo4j

Comment: Heh; it's certainly true that FaceBook has a planetary scale data management challenge on their hands, and that sheer scale requires ultra-custom solution. But too many in the industry tend to think of the big boys (FaceBook, Amazon, Google, etc) as being "cool" and "leading the way" when in fact their use cases aren't really representative of most industries and uses.  1B reads/sec is not a common tech requirement.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You might want to check out [this slide deck](http://www.slideshare.net/MDavidAllen1/family-tree-of-data-provenance-and-neo4j-46405323) and in particular slides 18-22.

Your question could have a lot of details to it, but let me try to focus on the big pieces.  Graph databases are [naturally indexed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22821269/performance-of-arbitrary-queries-with-neo4j) by relationships. So graph databases will be good when you  need to traverse a lot of relationships.  Graphs themselves are very flexible, so they'll be good when the inter-connections between your data need to change from time to time, or when the data about your core objects that's important to store needs to change.   Graphs are a very natural method of modeling some (but not all) data sources, things like peer to peer networks, road maps, organizational structures, etc.

Graphs tend to not be good at managing huge lists of things.  For example, if you were going to build a customer transaction database with analytics (where you need 1 million customers, 50 million transactions, and all you do is post transactions all day long) then it's probably not a good fit.   RDBMS is great at that, notice how that use case doesn't exploit relationships really.

Make sure to read those two links I provided, they have much more discussion.

Answer (score 0):

For maintenance reasons, any service aggregating data feeds has until now been well advised to keep their sources independent.

If I want to explore relationships between different feeds, this can be done at application level, using data tracking (for example) user preferences amongst the other feeds.

Graph databases are about managing relationship complexity, but this complexity is in many cases a design choice. Putting all your kids in one bathtub is fine until you drop the soap..