# Graph database in distributed env

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-java-api

I have a question concerning graph databases! Is there a mechanism to use graph databases in a distributed environment?! I mean can you distribute a graph database?! Can we even traverse a graph database in a distributed environment?!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you can do it.
There are different databases which scale very good nowadays (JanusGraph, OrientDB, ArangoDB etc).
Even if you have a very big database which has to be scaled beyond a single datacenter to multiple geo-distributed datacenters you still has options.
For example, you can use JanusGraph with Cassandra / ScyllaDB storage backends. It will give you an option to asynchronously synchronize all your data from different datacenters.
Of course, there are some issues to be solved like consistency and so on but with today's tools, it's very possible to organize a distributed graph database.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j enterprise edition features clustering, read more on http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha.html.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use all sorts of graph databases in distributed environments.   Can you distribute a graph database?   Definitely yes.

**BUT** - distributing the same graph database in many different places (to speed up reads) is quite easy, and done all the time.   Distributing a ridiculously massive database (so that parts of the graph database are in a bunch of different places) is quite hard.

I recommend [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558589/neo4j-sharding-aspect) which talks about sharding and distributing databases.  Pay particular attention to the bit about "sharding is an anti-pattern".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you please give me more details?! I'm new to neo4j and I find it a bit hard to understand this point! Thanks.

Comment: Stefan Armbruster provided a specific link to where you can read more about doing this in neo4j.